# How to change the storage engine type on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I would like to use InnoDB as the storage engine on all my tables and databases. Is there a command I can run to change the type of my current tables to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM?

Also, is there a way to set this as the default so I don't have to do this again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following article will tell you how to set the default storage engine, how to explicitly use a specific engine during a CREATE TABLE command, and how to change the storage engine of existing tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html

Answer (score 20):

To change the storage engine of an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

To set InnoDB as default:

> Normally, this is MyISAM, but you can change it by using the `--default-storage-engine` or `--default-table-type` server startup option, or by setting the `default-storage-engine` or `default-table-type` option in the my.cnf configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use are using the mysql workbench there is a script menu option to change the engine of all tables.

Select Plugins > Utilities > Change storage engine of all all tables.

Answer (score 0):

Today in latest versions of MySQL DB, by default InnoDB comes as default DB Engine.
We can check by : (in CMD)

mysql> show engines;

or

mysql> select * from information_schema.engines;