# mysql error 150 with INNODB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add this table..

```
CREATE TABLE playersByUser (
    userid INT,
    playername VARCHAR(255),
    ordering tinyint,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id)
) ENGINE INNODB;
```

I know the error has to do with the `INNODB`, but what can I look at or change to make this work?

My users table has the column `id` that is auto increment and a primary field.

users TABLE

```
users
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
 `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=93 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_c
```

Comment: please post users table ddl too

Comment: What is the full text of the error?  That will probably help more than the error number.

Comment: Can you try removing the `ENGINE INNODB` part from your query? Usually it is understood at the settings level. Also, try to give us the entire error message. Even better, try googling the complete error message.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14888593?  Also `ENGINE INNODB` should be `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat error message is "ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'shbdn.playersByUser' (errno: 150)"

Comment: engine=INNODB doesn't help. I'll post my users table

Comment: The full error is ... `#1005 - Can't create table 'example.playersByUser' (errno: 150)`

Comment: Not sure, but does `playersByUser.userid` need to be a key (primary or index) before making the `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat No, the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint itself fills the index requirement.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Oh, ok.  I wasn't sure.

Comment: Wait, the `INT(11)` isn't the problem (that's the default display length). It's the mismatch between InnoDB and MyISAM engines.

Comment: @Paul Do you have a reason that the `users` table must be `MyISAM`? You aren't using a FULLTEXT index on it, for example.

Comment: To be honest, and please excuse me ignorance, I am not too sure what `MYISAM` OR `INNODB` mean or do.

Comment: @Paul They are the [table's storage engines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html). They have somewhat different capabilities, but for enforcing FK's InnoDB is typically used. MyISAM does not actually enforce them

Comment: So would I just change the users table to `INNODB` ?

Comment: @Paul That should do it, yes.

Comment: How would I go about changing an existing table's engine?

Comment: To change the engine of an existing table. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1780111/541091

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks that worked perfectly!

Comment: It actually works if both are INNODB:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bc6c.